# Post Events to Facebook Page programmatically

Tags: facebook

Okay, I really tried to solve my problem on my own here, but I just don't understand Facebook and all the protocols there.

I have the following setup:
A Homepage like www.xyz.com
A Facebook Page like https://www.facebook.com/xyz

We are developing a homepage for a non-profit cinema. There are three screenings a week. At some point, the screenings are published.

When the screenings are published, I want the homepage (programmed with SilverStripe 3) to publish those as events to the Facebook Page.

My Problem: I don't want a user to log in to facebook to publish the events, because not everyone has admin permission there. Also, screenings should be published by the homepage itself without supervision.

So I figured, I need an app in Facebook, but I'm not sure with that either. Because that app should be restricted to only be used by my own page.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you want to [authenticate as a page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/)

The easiest way is:

- have a page admin visit the [graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer),
- get an access token with the `manage_pages` permission
- type `me/accounts` into the box to the right of the word "GET'

This will give you a list of pages and an access tokens for each page they admin. This token will be valid until an admin resets it manually from the page admin interface.

You can store this in a variable and make your calls to add events using these. Make sure you fail gracefully should the token get changed in the future.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted. One Problem though: If I debug the token it says, that it'll expire in about an hour. That differs from what you describe. Why?

Comment: Hmmmm. That's different than the last time I looked at it. If you want a permanent access token, it looks like your only option is an [app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/)